# Accessing values of individual JTextFields created in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, swing, for-loop, jtextfield

Here is how I created the labels and JTextFields:

```
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new SpringLayout());
    String[] labels = {"Non-animated image name:","Left animation image name:","Top animation image name:",
            "Right animation image name:","Bottom animation image name:"};
    for(int i=0; i<labels.length; i++){
        JLabel l = new JLabel(labels[i],JLabel.TRAILING);
        JTextField n = new JTextField(10);
        panel3.add(l);
        l.setLabelFor(n);
        panel3.add(n);
    }

    SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel3,
            5, 2,
            6, 6,
            6, 6);
```

Say for example, how would I access/get the value of the text in the JTextField with the label, "Top animation image name:"?

I know that usually, one can perform JTextField.getText(), but to me it looks like that wouldn't work here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: store the labels in an array so you can access them later in the program. or you could get all components of the panel and loop through it but that would be a little inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a specific example of the question:

> how can I access an object created in a loop.

The answer is the same: put them in a collection or array. Note that the collection option has greater flexibility. For instance if you create a bunch of JLabel/JTextField associations, you could use a `HashMap<String, JTextField>` to associate the JTextField with a String.

For example:

```
Map<String, JTextField> fieldMap = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();
String[] labels = {"Non-animated image name:","Left animation image name:","Top animation image name:",
        "Right animation image name:","Bottom animation image name:"};
for(int i=0; i<labels.length; i++){
    JLabel l = new JLabel(labels[i],JLabel.TRAILING);
    JTextField n = new JTextField(10);
    panel3.add(l);
    l.setLabelFor(n);
    panel3.add(n);
    fieldMap.put(labels[i], n);
}

// and then later you can get the text field associated with the String:
String text = fieldMap.get(labels[2]).getText();
```

Or for a full example:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class InputForm extends JPanel {
   private static final int COLUMNS = 10;
   private static final int GAP = 3;
   private static final Insets LABEL_INSETS = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, 15);
   private static final Insets TEXTFIELD_INSETS = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);
   private String[] labelTexts;
   private Map<String, JTextField> fieldMap = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();

   public InputForm(String[] labelTexts) {
      this.labelTexts = labelTexts;
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      for (int i = 0; i < labelTexts.length; i++) {
         String text = labelTexts[i];
         JTextField field = new JTextField(COLUMNS);
         fieldMap.put(text, field);

         addLabel(text, i);
         addTextField(field, i);
      }
   }

   public String[] getLabelTexts() {
      return labelTexts;
   }

   private void addTextField(JTextField field, int row) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.gridx = 1;
      gbc.gridy = row;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.insets = TEXTFIELD_INSETS;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      add(field, gbc);
   }

   private void addLabel(String text, int row) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = row;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.insets = LABEL_INSETS;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      add(new JLabel(text), gbc);
   }

   public String getFieldText(String key) {
      String text = "";
      JTextField field = fieldMap.get(key);
      if (field != null) {
         text = field.getText();
      }
      return text;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      String[] labelTexts = new String[] { "One", "Two",
            "Three", "Four" };
      InputForm inputForm = new InputForm(labelTexts);

      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, inputForm, "Enter Stuff Here",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
         for (String text : labelTexts) {
            System.out.printf("%20s %s%n", text, inputForm.getFieldText(text));
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you! You responded before I finished typing my followup question.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you create a `JLabel` and a `JTextField`, store references to each of them inside a new instance of a container class.

For example:

```
private class LabelTextFieldContainer {
    JLabel label;
    JTextField textField;

    //Constructor goes here...
}


for(int i=0; i<labels.length; i++){
    JLabel l = new JLabel(labels[i],JLabel.TRAILING);
    JTextField n = new JTextField(10);
    panel3.add(l);
    l.setLabelFor(n);
    panel3.add(n);

    containerList.add( new Container(l, n) );  //Instantiate List<LabelTextFieldContainer> containerList somewhere else
}
```